# After form submit Make a alert with Success message PHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

I have a fully working form that sends emails on submit, I would like to have some kind of alert if the email is sent successfully. I saw a lot of solutions with jquery or other libraries  but I wanna do it with php

```
<?php 



 if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['email'] !='') {

 

    $userName = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $messageSubject =$_POST['subject'];
    $catalog =$_POST['select_catalog'];
    $inputsValue =$_POST['radioSet1'];
    $inputsValue2 =$_POST['radioSet2'];
    $inputsValue3 =$_POST['radioSet3'];
    $inputsValue4 =$_POST['radioSet4'];
    
    
    $to = "levchegochev@gmail.com";
    
    $body = "";
    $body = "Akademija Za dizajn"."\r\n";
    $body .= "Ime: ".$userName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Prezime: ".$lastName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Telefonski broj:".$phoneNumber."\r\n";
    $body .= "Nacin na plakanje: ".$catalog. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Opcii: ".$inputsValue. "\r\n".$inputsValue2. "\r\n" .$inputsValue3. "\r\n" .$inputsValue4."\r\n";
    
  
    

  
  mail($to,$messageSubject, $body);

       if(mail = true ) {
         echo 'test'
       }
  
 


 }




?>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery, an alert can be done with plain JavaScript - as can displaying a more sophisticated html/css-based modal. In fact you can display such a modal just with PHP if you echo it in its displayed state, but you'd need JavaScript to allow the user to dismiss it again

Comment: `if (condition=true)` should be changed to  `if (condition)`  or `if (condition==true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
if(mail == true ) {
     echo '<script>alert("Email send!");</script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    if(mail) echo '<script>alert("message")</script>';
```